# Issue with UICollectionView reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uicollectionview

Im using `UICollectionView` for my project. But i get some issue with it: `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is not working when i call `reloadData` and scroll. This is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [listImage count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView1 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"indexpath %d", indexPath.row);
    NSString *cellIdentify = @"HomeCollectionViewCell";

    HomeCollectionViewCell *cell = (HomeCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView1 dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentify forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [listImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //set image pop-up for  first time login
    UIImageView *imageViewSignUp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_popupSignUp.png"]];
    if (indexPath.row == 5 && ![IQUser currentUser]) {
        imageViewSignUp.frame = CGRectMake(120, self.view.frame.size.height-100, 60, 63);
        [self.view addSubview:imageViewSignUp];
    }

    //set data for product or share
    [cell.contentView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        NSString *string = [[dictionary objectForKey:kDetail] objectForKey:kImage];

        if ([string rangeOfString:@"http://"].location != NSNotFound) {
            [self setImageWithString:cell.imageView aURL:string];
        } else {
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:string];
        }


    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

}
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {

}

-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView1 layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize size = collectionView.frame.size;
    return size;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

}
```

it is a issue on collectionView?!

Comment: please give the code for how you are calling the reload data and scroll. [self.collectionView reloadData] should work always.

Answer (score 0):

What is not working with UICollectionView ? please specify your problem.

And why are you setting image on UIView in cellForItemAtIndexPath

UIImageView *imageViewSignUp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_popupSignUp.png"]];
if (indexPath.row == 5 && ![IQUser currentUser]) {
    imageViewSignUp.frame = CGRectMake(120, self.view.frame.size.height-100, 60, 63);
    [self.view addSubview:imageViewSignUp];
}

Comment: oh, it is a different image that i want to show, like  a pop up.